# exception in creating xml file using xml outputter

Tags: java, xml

here is my simple code:

```
try
                {
                    Element performances = new Element("performances");
                    Document doc = new Document(performances);
                    doc.setRootElement(performances);

                    performances.setAttribute(new Attribute("date", dateFormat.format(cal.getTime())));

                    Element uptime = new Element("uptime");
                    uptime.addContent(new Element("days").setText(new Long(duptime).toString()));
                    uptime.addContent(new Element("hours").setText(new Long(huptime).toString()));
                    uptime.addContent(new Element("minutes").setText(new Long(muptime).toString()));
                    uptime.addContent(new Element("seconds").setText(new Long(suptime).toString()));

                    doc.getRootElement().addContent(uptime);

                    XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();

                    xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
                    xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileWriter("/homa/mazzy/Scrivania/perfor_"+dateFormat.format(cal.getTime())+"xml"));
```

I got this exception

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.jdom2.IllegalAddException: The element "performances" could not be added as the root of the document: The Content already has an existing parent document
```

but I don't know what does it means.where is the mistake?

Comment: this kind of exceptions raised if you trying to add second root element into exicted dom tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines

```
Document doc = new Document(performances);
doc.setRootElement(performances);
```

cause the error. The first sets the root, the second dies it again.

**Edit**

Do

```
Document doc = new Document()
doc.setRootElement(performances)
```

or

```
Document doc = new Document(performances)
```

Comment: so the two lines are the same?

Comment: see http://jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/Document.html#Document%28org.jdom2.Element%29 and http://jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/Document.html#setRootElement%28org.jdom2.Element%29